# Mapping a `Throwable?` to a `Result<Unit>` in Kotlin

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, option-type

What I'm trying to do, is map my `Throwable?` to a `Result.failure` or `Result.success` depending on its presence.

I figured this should be done with:

```
val a: Throwable? = Throwable()
val b = a?.let { Result.failure<Unit>(it) } ?: Result.success(Unit)
```

But the error I'm getting is: `Expression of type kotlin.Result cannot be used as a left operand of '?:'` which seems to imply the result of my `let` is non-nullable. I'm not sure how that's possible? I understood `let` as analogous to `map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Result<T>` cannot be used as a direct result type of Kotlin functions, *properties of Result type are also restricted*

From [Result KEEP's future advancement](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/result.md#future-advancements)

> Kotlin nullable types have extensive support in Kotlin via operators ?., ?:, !!, and T? type constructor syntax. We can envision better integration of Result into the Kotlin language in the future. However, unlike nullable types, that are often used to represent non signalling failure that does not cary additional information, Result instances also carry additional information and, in general, shall be always handled in some way. Making Result an integral part of the language also requires a considerable effort on improving Kotlin type system to ensure proper handling of encapsulated exceptions.

you can use something like

```
val b: Result<Unit> = if (a != null) {
        Result.failure(a)
    } else {
        Result.success(Unit)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`Result` is an experimental `inline` class so it has some limitations. For now the use of Kotlin null-safety operators `.?`, `?:` and `!!` is not allowed on both nullable and non-null Result types. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/result.md#limitations